# edit symbol in Illustrator using javascript

Tags: javascript, automation, symbols, adobe-illustrator

I am trying to create a symbol or copy selected objects to a symbol in Illustrator 5.1 using JavaScript with no success. Here is my code:

```
sourceDoc.selection = null; // deselect everything  
sourceDoc.selectObjectsOnActiveArtboard(); // select all in artboard  
sel = sourceDoc.selection;
sourceDoc.symbols.add(sel); // <--- NOT WORKING

for (k=0; k<sel.length; k++) {         
    var newItem = sel[k].duplicate(destDoc.symbols.getByName("Symbol1"),ElementPlacement.PLACEATEND); 
    //^^^^ NOT WORKING
}
```

Please help me how to fix this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`sourceDoc.selection` needs an index number to be a successful reference.

Use `sourceDoc.selection[0]` for example

if you have e.g. four items then the last created item is on index 0 and the first is on 3.